# Hosting Switched to Windows 2008 IIS7.5 and HttpHandlers Do Not Work

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-7.5, httphandler, shared-hosting

My hosting company just upgraded to IIS7.5 on Windows 2008, and my custom HttpHandlers have stopped working.  These were in place on my site in order to create custom friendly URLs (ie. http://www.domain.com/nice-informative-name instead of http://www.domain.com/page.aspx?id=12345).  In all my efforts to update the handler definitions in my web.config I continue to get 404 errors for the friendly URLs.

Here is an example of the original definition that previously worked:

```
<add verb="*" path="*/keyword/*" type="MyNamespace.Services.HttpHandlerManager" />
```

The last definition I have tried is this:

```
<add name="Keyword" verb="*" path="*/keyword/*" 
type="MyNamespace.Services.HttpHandlerManager" modules="IsapiModule" 
scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" allowPathInfo="false" 
preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
```

Comment: Is your AppPool set to Classic or Integrated Pipeline? If you are coming from IIS6, try setting it back to Classic.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you came from IIS 6.

The web.config sections changed.  Under IIS 6, you used the System.Web/HttpHandlers area.  For IIS 7 it is now under system.webServer/handlers.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763179.aspx